# Fractional dimensions for Window, like getBoundingClientRect()?

Tags: javascript

I want to compare the height of the window VS an HTMLElement.

For the HTMLElement I use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), which returns precise measurements for width and height as a float. This is important because it accounts for display scaling.

But the Window object doesn't seem to have an API for measuring its size in this way.

Best thing I've come up so far is constructing a custom [DOMRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRect/DOMRect):

```js
const domRect = new DOMRect({
  x: 0, y: 0, // x & y of window is always 0
  width: window.innerWidth, 
  height: window.innerHeight,
});
```

But `window.innerWidth` and `-Height` return rounded values, so they don't offer the precision that `getBoundingClientRect()` does.

I've considered using the [Visual Viewport API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Visual_Viewport_API) but then I might run into problems where the Visual Viewport differs from the Layout Viewport.

In short: Is there some API for obtaining window dimensions that is consistent with `getBoundingClientRect()` ? Or some properties that return fractional values for width and height so I can construct a custom DOMRect?

**Update: example**

As mentioned in the comments, it's actually not common (or possible, even?) to have a window that is non-whole pixel size.

That said, the example below returns a fractional height for the body element, while the window is a rounded, slightly lower integer.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body > * { 
  flex: none; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <!-- Content -->
</body>
</html>
```

```js
document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
// returns { height: 1019.2000122070312, ... }

window.innerHeight;
// returns 1019
```

[Live example based on code above](https://testcase.rejh.nl/2009-cr--body-domrect/)

**Update: fractional element size is a thing**

These results are for Chrome 96. I've tested it in Firefox (Windows) and Safari (iPad) and they both return round integers for the element height, which made me believe this might actually be a bug in Chrome.

So I filed a [Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1281175), and this is working as intended. They also mentioned that the element size may become fractional when the user zooms the page.

In other words: a body (or other element) may return a fractional value even when it's 100% of the window - but the window will return a rounded value. I assume that the window, in this case, may actually be fractional, so I'm looking for a way to retrieve that fractional value.

So my question remains: Is there some API for obtaining window dimensions that is consistent with `getBoundingClientRect()` ? Or some properties that return fractional values for width and height so I can construct a custom DOMRect?

Comment: How would you get your window to be a non-whole pixel size in the first place?

Comment: @DBS - :grins: *That* is indeed the elephant in the room.

Comment: @DBS That... is a good question. But for some reason I can have a `div` set to 100% width/height with getBoundingClient() returning a float slightly higher than the integers I get from window.innerWidth and -Height :(

Comment: Could you include a reproducing example of your inconsistent height element/window? There are a few things that can stop elements being exactly the expected size (Usually CSS or whitespace) it might be something that can be fixed there, rather than in the JS.

Comment: @DBS Added an example - then tested it in Firefox and that actually returns a nice, round value for the element height. So may be I've stumbled upon a Chrome bug. Since I did write the entire example, I did update the Q. If this turns out to be a bug, I should probably delete this Q.

Comment: Looks like the window can be non-whole pixels: if the user zooms, it may actually be a fractional value but there doesn't seem to be a way to retrieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You could give an element

```css
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
visibility: hidden;
```

and use `getBoundingClientRect` on it.